# I think I uninstalled my system settings. How can I get it back?

Tags: system-settings

What's the name of the package I need to install to get the control panel(System Settings) back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install it again(Ubuntu 12.04):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

Ubuntu 14.04+

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for a quick fix. This will also take care of any other packages that might have been lost. After installation, the system settings icon will automatically start appearing in the launcher.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I assume that would take care of other packages that got lost? Good idea! Could you add that to the answer? ( I can do it, if you confirm?)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I have edited the answer. Thank you.